# Palabos - C++ - Signal code: Address not mapped error

Tags: c++

I am working with Palabos open source code. The code is given on [this Github](https://github.com/gladk/palabos) repository. I am trying to select a lid using tagLids function, and I expect to get an integer as a return. To do this, I am using [triangleBoundary3D.h](https://github.com/gladk/palabos/blob/0a71c79bd5e7d26d1f4e1136e568c0c9a5e0540e/src/offLattice/triangleBoundary3D.h) and [triangleBoundary3D.hh](https://github.com/gladk/palabos/blob/0a71c79bd5e7d26d1f4e1136e568c0c9a5e0540e/src/offLattice/triangleBoundary3D.hh) .

tagLids function requires a cuboid coordinates, and it tags all lids whose barycenters are inside the given cuboid and return the integer tag.

For this, I tried to use the following code. I wrote "Done" on to the screen to check where the code fails. My code is:

```
Array<T,3> upperRightCorner = Array<T,3>(0., 0., 0.);
Array<T,3> lowerLeftCorner = Array<T,3>(0.015, 0.015, 0.015);
TriangleBoundary3D<T> *triangleBoundary;
Cuboid<T> aCuboid;
aCuboid.lowerLeftCorner = lowerLeftCorner;
aCuboid.upperRightCorner = upperRightCorner;
pcout << "Done 1" << std::endl;
plint inlet1 = triangleBoundary->tagLids(aCuboid);
pcout << "Done 2" << std::endl;
pcout << inlet1 << std::endl;
```

and the output is:

```
Done 1
[ubuntu:03772] *** Process received signal ***
[ubuntu:03772] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ubuntu:03772] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ubuntu:03772] Failing at address: 0x150
[ubuntu:03772] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) 
[0x7f233dcd6890]
[ubuntu:03772] [ 1] ./externalFlowAroundObstacle(+0x16194)[0x5560d67b1194]
[ubuntu:03772] [ 2] ./externalFlowAroundObstacle(+0x10a8a)[0x5560d67aba8a]
[ubuntu:03772] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) 
[0x7f233d8f4b97]
[ubuntu:03772] [ 4] ./externalFlowAroundObstacle(+0x110da)[0x5560d67ac0da]
[ubuntu:03772] *** End of error message ***
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can I get an integer from tagLids function?

Comment: `triangleBoundary` is never assigned anything, so dereferencing it is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Frank thank you very much for your comment! what do you suggest me to do?